# Spring Sort by Value with Page

Tags: spring

There are about 100 product objects in the database. Users upload products to the system.

I  want to show these products on the homepage, I want to show which product it is.

First, i wanted to do this with List. But in order not to tire the database, i wanted to use Page. But, I couldn't figure out how can i sort there records.

This is my Service:

```
 public Page<Market> getMarketItemsByPage(Pageable page,String pName) {
        Page<Market> allProductsSortedByName = marketRepository.findAllByProductName(pName,page);
        return allProductsSortedByName;
    }
```

This is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MarketRepository extends JpaRepository<Market, Long> {

    Page<Market> findAllByProductName(String pName ,Pageable pageable);

    List<Market> findByUserId(Long id);

}
```

I want to show the last 10 products added on the page. I can do this with List easily, but according to my research, if i use page, the app is less tired.

Comment: How do you construct `Pageable` object? Sorting order is already part of `Pageable`, you just need to configure it (specify field(s) and order).

Comment: But it sorts elements in Page=1 for example. I want to sort from all data

Answer (score 0):

You've to create Pageable with Sort like below:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,size, Sort.by("pName").descending());
```